# Merging/unifying polygons from same layer when boundaries are touching using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, merge

I have a big layer full of polygons. The ones that are separated, are individualized. However, I want to join the ones that have their boundaries touching each other (look at the image).
For example, if at the beginning I have 20.500 polygons, I want to have 10.000.

With the Merge option in ArcGIS, the polygons get merged with only one polygon, which isn't good for working.

I don't mind if the attribute table gets wrong, as I will create a new one.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried dissolve?

Comment: I’ve removed QGIS from your title and as a tag to keep your question focused. Feel free to ask a similar, separate question about it if you wish.

Comment: @FelixIP Yes. However, as I don't have an exact value that these polygons (ones that its boundary touches the others' boundary) share it creates a single feature, unifying all the polygons. I think it should be easy to do this geo-process, but I don't find the way... Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @PolyGeo Ok, thank you.

Comment: If there is only 1 common point between 2 polygons try a) tiny buffer with dissolve all option b) convert them to single part c)run near of original and single parts d) dissolve original by near_fid.

Comment: Have you tried converting polygons to raster and convert raster to polygons back?

Comment: Thank you @FelixIP, I could solve it by creating a very tiny buffer!

Comment: @Amadeus the majority of these polygons come from a raster! I converted them to vector data. Thanks.